# SO Collapsed Comments Are Not Accessible Offline

Tags: feature-request, comments

Sometimes I save *Stack Overflow* pages for viewing offline at a later time because I may not have an internet connection.

My Google Chrome app saves them as `.mhtml` files.

All is well except for one thing. *Stack Overlow* pages hide (collapse) some of the comments if there are too many. The user clicks on "*show n more comments*" to expand the comment group.

Clicking on "*show n more comments*" does not work offline while viewing a saved copy.

I have tried expanding all comments prior to saving, but that does not help.

The only other alternative now is to "*Select All*" and save as text. But that is unpleasant. And sometimes does not work due to large size.

Please make all comments accessible for viewing offline when viewing saved pages.

Comment: *"I have tried expanding all comments prior to saving, but that does not help."* Why would that not help? That should be a solution. Alternatively, you can save the page as a PDF. I don't think that this general feature request is going to go very far; Stack Overflow loads a *lot* of stuff with asynchronous AJAX requests, and they aren't likely to rebuild the comment system just for this niche use-case.

Comment: @CodyGray: PDF would not be nearly as good as HTML. And I my Chrome app does not even have that option.

Comment: You could use Firefox, which does save the page with expanded comments, if you've loaded them prior to saving the page.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of saving the page as HTML, which excludes dynamically-loaded content due to the fact that the browser re-fetches the original page from the server (without AJAX-loaded content like expanded comments), I recommend **printing (saving) to PDF** instead.

I have a [StackPrintStyles](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/StackPrintStyles.user.js) userscript that provides a one-click button to help you load all answers (if there are more than one page of answers in that question) as well as load all comments under those answers.

Screenshot of button: [image: screenshot of button]

After clicking that (and allowing a short moment for the answers and comments to load), simply print the page and then save the print preview as a PDF file.

Other nifty features of this userscript:

- responsive print styles for all sites on the network, as well as chat and chat transcripts
- strips out unnecessary information from the page, leaving just the main Q&A content
- preserve links in the PDF
- automatically converts all relative timestamps to absolute UTC ones
- one answer per page
- works with [Post Headers & Question Table of Contents](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/PostHeadersQuestionToc.user.js) to provide an answer header (with author, timestamp, permalink, revision link, timeline link)
- works with [New Comments Layout](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/NewCommentsLayout.user.js) for easier comment readability
- if moderator, also have an option to load deleted comments

Comment: An alternative is [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/). It seems to include all comments.